# Problem to see the color preview when autocomplete

Tags: colors, visual-studio-code

I've begun working with tailwind in my VSCode
I've installed some extensions (I had other prev. installed)

```
bierner.color-info
bradlc.vscode-tailwindcss
burkeholland.simple-react-snippets
christian-kohler.npm-intellisense
CoenraadS.bracket-pair-colorizer-2
dbaeumer.vscode-eslint
dsznajder.es7-react-js-snippets
EditorConfig.EditorConfig
esbenp.prettier-vscode
felixfbecker.php-intellisense
flowtype.flow-for-vscode
JakeWilson.vscode-cdnjs
MehediDracula.php-namespace-resolver
mgmcdermott.vscode-language-babel
msjsdiag.vscode-react-native
naumovs.color-highlight
NuclleaR.vscode-extension-auto-import
oderwat.indent-rainbow
PKief.material-icon-theme
royaction.color-manager
runningcoder.react-snippets
zhuangtongfa.material-theme
```

My problem is that I cannot see the color preview for each class in the autocomplete list (See image)...

I've tried disabling all of them, enabling only tailwind intellisense, w/o luck

Thanks for any tip you can give me

PS: Latest VSCode version on Windows 8.1 Pro

[image: color preview autocomplete]

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a bug in Tailwind CSS Intellisense

https://github.com/bradlc/vscode-tailwindcss/issues/113

Installing the alpha release solved it